# How does strong parameter prevent users to insert malicious code into a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

Rails newbie working on the official Rails guide.

I don't understand how using a strong parameter works as a security gateway since users could still put in malicious text within the parameters permitted through strong parameter.

Comment: strong parameters only determines which parameters is permitted to be posted. escaping and other security checks is beyond this scope. 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong parameters prevent your model from setting attributes which should not be set.

Imagine this: you have a model `User` with fields `name` and `role`. Obviously, your users can update their names, but they should not be able to update their roles.

Without strong parameters, your controller may look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # params: {user: {role: 'administrator'}}
  end
end
```

And user will be able to update their role and gain admin permissions.

With strong parameters:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user.update_attributes(params_for_update) # params_for_update: {}
  end

  private

  def params_for_update
     params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Protecting from malicious parameters is another topic. You should sanitize your params. Partially rails doing it as well - for example, by escaping strings in query methods:

```
User.where(name: "'; drop table users;").to_sql
# =>  "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"name\" = '''; drop table users;'"
```